# 2D SpriteKit LipSync

Tags: sprite-kit, 2d-games

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do 2D character lip sync in SpriteKit?

To be clear we are looking to do something like you see in SpeakAZoo in the AppStore.  We will render the various mouth positions (phonemes) ... and at runtime we want to be able to decode some audio and put up the correct mouth position in sync.  This is 100% "2D" with illustrated characters.

Looking for either a product, API or guidance in how best to proceed.  We have a large variety of audio that our characters can say.

Anyone used any products which work well in iOS/ObjectiveC/

Comment: doing it in sprite kit is not hard,  just do it like how southpark gets made,  have a sprite object for your mouth,  and place the correct mouth shape bases on the audio that is currently being played.  Now getting the correct shape based on audio is where you will get most of your trouble

Comment: What may be of interest is [Papagayo](http://lostmarble.com/papagayo-home/).  You put in an audio file, and start breaking apart the audio into words.  It then outputs a text file with the different sounds that the mouth should move to (such as "e").  I use it for lip-syncing in Blender with shape keys (one for each type of sound), but maybe this will help.  It would not run in real-time, but can be used to preprocess.